# Ruby on Rails undefined method 'to_datetime'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried to compare values from View with created_at from DB, but i have this problem **"undefined method `to_datetime' for {"year"=>"2015", "month"=>"11", "day"=>"7"}:ActionController::Parameters"**. I have no ideas.

Controller:

```
def data_search
    @SDB=[]
    startt=params[:start_date].to_datetime
    endt=params[:end_date].to_datetime
    Offer.where(created_at: [startt..endt]).each do |f|
        @SDB.push(f)
    end
end
```

Segment from search.html.erb:

```
        <%= select_date Date.today, :prefix => :start_date %> 
        <%= select_date Date.today, :prefix => :end_date%>
```

Without 'to_datetime' i have **bad value for range**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`to_datetime` is a method on strings, where as you appear to have some hashtables.

Some other form of conversion is needed. Something like
`DateTime.new(params[:start_date]["year"], params[:start_date]["month"], params[:start_date]["day"])` would probably work, although I'd advise making a separate function to convert a params hash into a DateTime (essentially wrapping that raw code in a cleaner function).

Comment: Thanks, its working!

Answer (score 0):

The parameter generated from your view is a hash with "year", "month", "day" in it. You need to convert it to a string like "2015-11-07" first and call `to_datetime` to get the datetime value. I changed a little of my codes in one of my project to fit your variables:

```
start_date = parames[:start_date][:year] + '-' + parames[:start_date][:month] + '-' + parames[:start_date][:day]
startt = start_date.to_datetime
```